# Getting 500 on sending request from REST API client

Tags: express

I am sending the following request to my `express` application

```
POST http://127.0.0.1:4000/users/register-user HTTP/1.1
content-type: application/json

{
    "firstname": "fn",
    "lastname": "l n",
    "email": "email@email.com",
    "password": "some pwd"
}
```

When the request hits the server, I get a `500`. I am not able to figure out why? Is there a way to debug `Express` i.e. make it print more information ?

The code in `app.js` which should handle request is

```
app.use(configData.configData.REGISTER_USER_URL, usersRouter.usersRouter); // a path with /users goes to userRouter. Not need really at present
...
app.get('/home', indexControllerModule.homepageHandler); 
app.get('/question', questionControllerModule.addQuestionHandler); 
console.log(`config is ${JSON.stringify(configData)}`)
app.post(configData.configData.REGISTER_USER_URL, usersControllerModule.addUserHandler);
```

...

```
// error handler
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
  // set locals, only providing error in development
  res.locals.message = err.message;
  res.locals.error = req.app.get('env') === 'development' ? err : {};
  console.log(`error at server: ${JSON.stringify(err)}`)
  // render the error page
  res.status(err.status || 500).json({message: "Error in handing request"});
  //res.render('error');
  //res.json({message:"404 error"})
});
```

The configuration seems ok.

```
config is {"configData":{"DATABASE_URL":"mongodb://0.0.0.0:27017/","QUESTIONS_DATABASE":"Questions","USERS_DATABASE":"Users","COLLECTION_AREA":"areas","COLLECTION_USERS":"users","EXPRESS_SERVER_TEST":"http://localhost:4000","HOMEPAGE_URL":"/home","ADD_QUESTION_URL":"/add-question","REGISTER_USER_URL":"/users/register-user"}}
```

I see the following trace on server `POST /users/register-user 500 28.754 ms - 38`

Answer (score 0):

I changed the error handler to print the `err` in `app.js`. turns out I was printing a circular object.

```
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
  // set locals, only providing error in development
  console.log(`error at server: ${JSON.stringify(err)}`)
  res.locals.message = err.message;
  console.log(`res is ${utils.inspect(res)}`)
  res.locals.error = req.app.get('env') === 'development' ? err : {};
  
  // render the error page
  res.status(err.status || 500).json({message: "Error in handing request"});
  //res.render('error');
  //res.json({message:"404 error"})
});
```